# how to get the 2nd row and the last row of a file using UTL_FILE

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a file which consists of thousand rows and I need to get a portion of the 2nd row (about 50 characters) and the last row of the file. Please advise. Thank you.

Im trying to do something like UTL_FILE.READLINE(fileloc, filename, nrow, lastrow).

SAMPLE:
Filename: CLOSED_SO_20190124.txt

```
DATA in the FILE:
    0246608377|22795124004|
    650930363|1-8IGO3S82920|
    0245563264|22669075004|
    0245563264|22669075004|
    164260364|1-2DFE-6573219|
    650821459|1-6HWQUF11209|

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

    650930363|1-8IGO3S82920|
    650821459|1-6HWQUF11209|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example.

Directory name & its location, as well as sample file contents:

```
SQL> select directory_name, directory_path from all_directories;

DIRECTORY_NAME                 DIRECTORY_PATH
------------------------------ --------------------
EXT_DIR                        c:\temp

SQL> $type c:\temp\sofile.txt
0246608377|22795124004|
650930363|1-8IGO3S82920|
0245563264|22669075004|
0245563264|22669075004|
164260364|1-2DFE-6573219|
650821459|1-6HWQUF11209|
SQL>
```

The procedure: a local counter (`l_cnt`) knows line number; if it is equal to `2`, display that line. Also, when nothing's being found (so exception handler section is executed), I've reached the end of the file so I'm displaying the last line as well.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    l_file utl_file.file_type;
  3    l_dir  varchar2(20) := 'EXT_DIR';
  4    l_name varchar2(20) := 'sofile.txt';
  5    l_line varchar2(50);
  6    l_cnt  number := 0;
  7  begin
  8    l_file := utl_file.fopen (l_dir, l_name, 'R');
  9    loop
 10      begin
 11        utl_file.get_line(l_file, l_line);
 12        l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
 13        if l_cnt = 2 then
 14           dbms_output.put_line('2nd : ' || l_line);
 15        end if;
 16      exception
 17        when no_data_found then
 18          dbms_output.put_line('last: ' || l_line);
 19          exit;
 20      end;
 21    end loop;
 22    utl_file.fclose(l_file);
 23  end;
 24  /
2nd : 650930363|1-8IGO3S82920|
last: 650821459|1-6HWQUF11209|

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 11g

```
select col 
from 
(
  select 
    rownum AS rnum, 
    LEFT(myCol, 50) col
  from Table1
  where Rownum < 3
)
WHERE rnum = 2
```

In Oracle 12c

```
select LEFT(mycol, 50) col
from Table1
ORDER BY val
OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

For the last row

```
select LEFT(mycol, 50) col
from my_table
where pk = ( select max(pk) from my_table )
```

then you can union them

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, but I am looking for the row of a FILE.

Comment: this gives your ROW, I could not understand what you mean

Comment: Hi, I actually need using UTL_FILE function on pl sql block, to read a file in a directory to get the rows needed.